# Making function with brackets

Tags: php

It's possibly to create function like if,when,for ?
I mean this:

```
<?php
function func_like_if($var1, $var2){
global $privileges;
$var3 = $var1+$var2;
if($var3 != $privileges){
// false - pass
}else{
//true - can't pass, do code
}
}

func_like_if('var1', 'var2'){ // <--- can write here brackets ? 
// true - do code
} //<--- can write here brackets ?
//false - don't
```

Comment: @RoyalBg you need to get out more then :)

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No, it is not possible, if you need to check what boolean a function returns, this is not the way... the way is `if(func(param)) { do if true }`

Comment: Direct question: Can I make a function (like if) with brackets and code insid

Comment: The creators of php were innovative enough to develop a built in function that can accomplish this very task. You can read about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Comment: um yes. functions often have code in them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overthinking it.

```
function my_test($var1, $var2){
  global $privileges;
  $var3 = $var1+$var2;
  if($var3 != $privileges){
    return false
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}

if( my_test('var1', 'var2') ) {
  // true - do code
} else {
  //false - don't
}
```

Assuming that that is just example code, because that really just condenses down to:

```
if ( $var1+$var2 == $privileges ) {}
```

and if the vars are strings you can't use `+` on them without implicit conversion to integer, and we sprial down the rabbit hole of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

That said, in reference to your general question about being able to create your own language constructs and/or operators in PHP: No.

Comment: One question. Use in_array() or array_search()?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ternary Operators

`$value = ("condition" ? true : false);`

I supose you want a true / false return. Please give us aditional info

Comment: I thinked about it but it's not solve my problem, I have eg. Input, user write command, and he got a staff = 5, for every command i must write if(staff){if(command){code}}, i have 100 commands and making more, can this long if code change to something other ?